# when click on the first li, it show content one, when click on second li, it shows content two

Tags: javascript

```
<style type="text/css">

.web_index div {width: 400px; height: 300px; background: #eee;}
    ul li{width: 100px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; list-style: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function licker(){
var lier=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var diver=document.getElementsByClassName("web_index")[0].getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i=0;i<lier.length;i++)
    { 
        for(j=0;j<diver.length;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
             diver[j].style.display=block;
                }
            else{
                diver[j].style.display=none;
                }   
            }
    }
}

</script>
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="licker()" class="li01">the first li</li>
    <li onclick="licker()" class="li02">the second li</li>
    <li onclick="licker()" class="li03">the third li</li>
    <div class="web_clear"></div>
</ul>
<div class="web_index">
<div style="display:block" >content one</div>
<div style="display:none">content two</div>
<div style="display:none">content three</div>
</div>
```

when click on the first li, it show content one, the others are all hidden, when click on second li, it shows content two. the others are all hidden....why my code doesn't work.how to correct it.thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign an index to your `li`'s:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="licker(0)" class="li01">the first li</li>
    <li onclick="licker(1)" class="li02">the second li</li>
    <li onclick="licker(2)" class="li03">the third li</li>
    <div class="web_clear"></div>
</ul>
```

and your function:

```
function licker(id){
    var diver=document.getElementsByClassName("web_index")[0].getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0;i<diver.length;i++){ 
        if(i==id){
            diver[i].style.display='block';
        } else {
            diver[i].style.display='none';
        }   
    }
}​
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f6Xx3/)

Comment: many thanks ,your javascript skill is gorgeous. could you tell me how to learn it, thank you.

Comment: mostly stay on Stackoverflow and View-Source :)

Comment: i am stay on Stackoverflow every day every time. but still don't know how to write some complex function of javascript.:)

Comment: Look at peoples answers, try to learn from them, try to solve a question by your self, use [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) .. you'll get it right at some point. You are are for last 3 weeks. Change that to 3 years and we'll talk :)

Comment: :) ok memory this promise. after 3 years, i will talk to you.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ul>
   <li onclick="licker(this);">the first li</li>
   <li onclick="licker(this);">the second li</li>
   <li onclick="licker(this);">the third li</li>
</ul>
<div class="web_index">
   <div style="display: block">content one</div>
   <div style="display: none">content two</div>
   <div style="display: none">content three</div>
```

```
function licker(sender) {
    var lier = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var diver = document.getElementsByClassName("web_index")[0].getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < lier.length; i++) {
       if (lier[i] != sender) continue;
       for (j = 0; j < diver.length; j++) {
          if (i == j)
             diver[j].style.display = 'block';
          else 
              diver[j].style.display = 'none';

          }
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sender is the `li` that has been clicked and during iteration on `lis` I check that the current `li` is clicked `li` or not.

Comment: could i delete this line if (lier[i] != sender) continue; thank you.

Comment: No that would produce unexpected results.